# What does the American idiomatic expression "2 x 4" exactly mean?

Tags: idioms

What does the American idiomatic expression "2 x 4"  exactly mean? I've read a very interesting book by Father Donald H. Calloway, *No turning back*  (an autobiography and a conversion story), and chapter 10 is entitled "The divine 2 x 4". Could that mean the divine surprise, the divine intervention?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumber#mediaviewer/File:2_By_4_Clue_Stick.jpg

Answer (score 3):

2x4 (two by four) is a standard size piece of wood (in nominal inches).

Being *hit by a 2x4* is a common idiom for sudden understanding or for surprise.

I imagine in this case Father Calloway has had a sudden understanding of something to do with religion, hence him describing the 2x4 as *divine* (from a God).

Edited to add some details from the comments below

'2x4' is the nominal cross-sectional size by some number of feet in length.

Comment: In fact, we often talk about giving someone a clue-by-four, in other words, correcting someone in a not-particularly-gentle way.

Comment: To clarify a little further, it refers to the dimensions of the cross-section of a beam or spar. A 2x4 would measure 2 inches by 4 inches by some number of feet.

Comment: On a technical level, the '2x4' is the *nominal* cross-sectional size -- typically the actual size is smaller (and varies by country).

Comment: Note that "2 x 4" is normally "two times four". It's only in the context of carpentry that it's pronounced "two-**by**-four". Note also that "a two-by-four" can be a count noun, meaning a plank of that size, or it can be a mass noun used in compounds, like _two-by-four stock_.

Comment: The US, where huge proportion of the population intimately participate in building or renovating our homes with the coincidence of standard sizes of lumber, as well as in coincidence with the widespread popularity of wood-based structures. Not so, in other countries where intimate involvement of big govt micromanages you from doing anything to your own home.

Comment: @JohnLawler Also worth noting that in the UK we'd call it a four by two normally, not a two by four. Same goes for a six by two or a six by four. Bigger number first.

Comment: In the US, the phrase is fixed and elided. /'tubəfor/, a 3-syllable noun.

Comment: @JohnLawler Same in the UK but with be for by _fourbetwo_